# XSLT for-each iteration

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I'm using a `for-each` in my `XSLT`. In my example `XML` I only have one element but the for-each is executing 13 times and I can't figure out why.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rowset>
            <xsl:for-each select="OUTPUT/eas:ShowDetailedRequestsByScheduleId/eas:ScheduleRequest">
                <xsl:variable name="status"/>
                <test>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@Schedule"/>
                </test>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </rowset>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<OUTPUT xmlns:eas="****************">
    <eas:ShowDetailedRequestsByScheduleId>
        <eas:ScheduleRequest PPR="" Schedule="New Standard Drum Filling Orders" createdBy="" createdOn="2014-05-03 01:14:06.973" endTime="" isaDescription="" isaId="50527" lastModifiedBy="" lastModifiedOn="" priority="1" startTime="">
            <eas:SegmentRequirement ScheduleRequest="50527" createdBy="root" createdOn="2014-05-03 01:14:06.973" duration="" durationUnitOfMeasure="" endTime="" isaDescription="" isaId="DF_FIlling" lastModifiedBy="root" lastModifiedOn="2014-05-03 01:14:06.973" startTime="">
                <eas:MaterialProducedRequirement createdBy="root" createdOn="2014-05-03 01:14:06.977" isaDescription="" isaId="" lastModifiedBy="root" lastModifiedOn="2014-05-03 01:14:06.977" location="" materialDefinition="51014-302" quantity="5.000000000000" quantityUnitOfMeasure=""/>
            </eas:SegmentRequirement>
        </eas:ScheduleRequest>
    </eas:ShowDetailedRequestsByScheduleId>
</OUTPUT>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rowset>
   <test />
   <test />
   <test />
   <test />
   <test>New Standard Drum Filling Orders</test>
   <test />
   <test />
   <test />
   <test />
   <test />
   <test />
   <test />
   <test />
</rowset>
```

Comment: well with you input, it would oly output 1 `<test>` and that is `<test>New Standard Drum Filling Orders</test>`

Comment: Yes but when I input here http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html I get the output with 13 test-tags

Comment: I am inclined to think that is a problem with the "freeformatter" website. You should not actually be getting any output because the XSLT in the question has a reference to an undeclared namespace (eas). If you add the namespace declaration `xmlns:eas="****************"` to your XSLT, you might find it working (and it might be worth trying it at a different website, such as http://xsltransform.net/)

Comment: I am using a namespace there, I just obfuscated it in my post here. I will try using a different tool.

Comment: The namespace is not defined in the XSLT, only in the XML. With the namespace definition copied into the XSLT, I get the expected output. Without it I get an error message.

Comment: @ThW thank you, I overlooked this. Post as answer and I will accept. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Namespace need to be defined in the XML and the XSLT, too. It is missing in the XSLT at the moment:

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:eas="****************">
<!-- ... --->      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<OUTPUT xmlns:eas="****************">
  <eas:ShowDetailedRequestsByScheduleId>
    <!-- ... ---> 
  </eas:ShowDetailedRequestsByScheduleId>
</OUTPUT>
```